# Break constant loop in arduino

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I am currently designing some code in C on an Arduino Uno that allows control of a 144 neopixel strip through a keypad. I've already sorted out interpretation of the keypad inputs and control of the strip. My problem however is that I want a mode which creates a rainbow, which I've done successfully, and can be broken out at any time by the press of the hash key (input code 13). This is my code at the moment:

```
void rainbow()
{
  uint16_t i, j;
  int keypressed = 0;
  while (keypressed != -13)
  {          
    for(j=0; j<256; j++)
    {        
      for(i=0; i< 144; i++) 
      {        
        pixels.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / 144) + j) & 255));        
      }                        
      pixels.show();    
      keypressed = ((int)(kpd.getKey())) - 48;   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong button

Comment: It would also help if your question contained a question...

Comment: Yours is a strange way of testing for the `'#'` key. Its ASCII value is `35` so `35 - 48` is `-13` what you test for. But why not skip the `-48` and simply just test for `'#'`? It looks as though there will be code that uses the number digits `'0'` to `'9'` and if so it would be clearer to subtract `'0'`.